# openldap and memberof property

Tags: zend-framework, ldap, openldap, base-class

I'm trying to make auth with LDAP (Zend_Ldap) and using openldap server.
Groups objects implements two classes: posixGroup and top
Users objects implements two classes: inetOrgPerson, posixAccount and top.

User object has no properties like "memberof", where I can see all user groups.
I can get user to groups relaions from groups propertie "memberuid", but it's not so usable, as in case with "memverof" propety.

Wich classes I must implement for users objects to get memberof field or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is really 'you don't want to do that'. You want to add the user to the group, not the other way around. You can find the groups the user is a member of with a simple search filter.

Having said that, there are dynamic membership and dynamic lists overlays in OpenLDAP that can do this for you. But it's really just putting the same thing as above under the hood.